# how to manage a project which contains files specific to different OS?

Tags: java, git, maven, github

we have a project which initially was developed to run on a linux platform, we want to customize it and use it under windows platform. It is hosted on github. Any advice on how to manage files that are shared between the two platforms but have some specificity for each one. for example configuration files that contains paths, environment variables and the like.

thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged maven here is the solution, use profiles to differentiate between linux and windows.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>linux</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <envName>linux</envName>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>windows</id>
        <properties>
            <envName>windows</envName>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.class</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>${project.basedir}/target/classes/configurations</targetPath>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/configurations/${envName}</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
</build>
```

Say suppose you have some configuration files specific to OS. and when you want to build based on the enivronment you want the file to copied to configurations directory inside class, the above code snippet copies that. For that to work you need to create 2 directories inside `src/main/resoruces/configurations/linux` and `src/main/resources/configurations/windows`. when you run maven you need to use profile like mvn package -Plinux or mvn package -Pwindows.

Comment: thanks for suggestion i certainly will take it into account. But my question is more related to gitHub than maven. the problem is that for   both platforms they share the same config files which contain config params for file paths. As wrote above we are customizing a project to be used in windows platform

Comment: I've no idea about Github, what I believe its SCM and it is not build script. Hence I hope your folder structure remains same as that of maven, Hence if you are using maven you need to create two directories as mentioned above. and you can get both the code to your disk and use profile.